# Linq to SQL Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, expression

Can someone tell me why I can't select new objects from MS SQL database in Entity Framework in this way:

```
public static Expression<Func<LeaveDay, bool>> IsInDatesRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate){
   return ld => ld.StartDate <= endDate && ld.EndDate >= startDate;
}


this.ObjectContext.People.Select(p => new NewPeopleObject
    {
      Guid = p.Guid,
      FirstName = p.FirstName,
      LastName = p.LastName,
      LeaveDays = p.CalendarData.LeaveDays.AsQueryable()
      .Where(LeaveDayExpressions.IsInDatesRange(startDate, endDate))
      .Select(ld => new LeaveDaySummary
         {
             StartDate = ld.StartDate,
             EndDate = ld.EndDate,
         })
    })
```

Without `AsQueryable()` I can't compile application, because `LeaveDayExpressions.IsInDatesRange` is static Expression. I have tried pass only Func to `Where` clause but it throws Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025. With Expression and `AsQueryable` on `LeaveDays` I get this exception:

> Code supposed to be unreachable

People is `ObjectSet` collection with one `CalendarData` object on one `People` and `CalendarData` has `EntityCollection` set of `LeaveDays`.

`NewPeopleObject` is a class with few properties and `IEnumarable` `LeaveDaySummaries` collection.

What can I do to pass Expression to `Where` clause without parsing linq to sql error?

Comment: As far as I can tell you don't show us how LeaveDayExpressions is defined.  Kinda hard to help without being able to see that.

Comment: I edited my code above.

Comment: Yeah that still does not make sense.  Are you trying to make an extension method?  Then the syntax should be something like `.Where(L => L.IsInDatesRange(startDate, endDate))`

Comment: It's not extension, it's an expression to filter LeaveDays in database query. It works fine with `ObjectSet` like    `this.ObjectContext.LeaveDays.Where(LeaveDayExpressions.IsInDatesRange(startDate, endDate))`   but it doesn't work with `EntityCollection` and I don't know why.

Comment: I'd say you can't use it in entity-framework then.

Comment: Can you tell my why? Any documentations about that or something? Or maybe some workarounds.

Comment: Why? EF has to translate from Linq to SQL. If you give it a construct it can't translate then it can't translate it. Replace the function with the return statement from your example.

Answer (score 6):

I can't test the exact case (`ObjectContext`, `ObjectSet` etc. indicate some older EF version), but I was able to reproduce both aforementioned runtime exceptions in the latest EF6.1.3 (using `DbContext` and `DbSet`) as well.

Let forget about `Func` approach - EF needs to translate the query to SQL, so `Expression` is a must. Which in turn requires `AsQueryable()`. So far so good.

The problem is that EF does not like custom methods inside expression tree - it usually has no issues with top level methods, but definitely has issue with nested calls like in the sample (the problematic expression is part of the outer select expression).

I can't tell why, but in most of the cases (including this and when possible) putting the expression into local variable outside of the query and using it inside resolves the issue:

```
var leaveDayPredicate = LeaveDayExpressions.IsInDatesRange(startDate, endDate);
var result = this.ObjectContext.People.Select(p => new NewPeopleObject
{
    Guid = p.Guid,
    FirstName = p.FirstName,
    LastName = p.LastName,
    LeaveDays = p.CalendarData.LeaveDays.AsQueryable()
        .Where(leaveDayPredicate)
        .Select(ld => new LeaveDaySummary
        {
             StartDate = ld.StartDate,
             EndDate = ld.EndDate,
        })
});
```

For more advanced scenarios (like expression using something from the outer expression), you might need some expression processing library, for instance [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) `Invoke` / `Expand` / `AsExpandable` custom extension methods etc.